# How to process all frame using cv2

Tags: python, opencv

The code unable to process the last frame of the video

The following code execute flawless except when handling the last frame

where it shot the following error

```
error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

def FrameCapture(path):

```
def FrameCapture (path): #Path to video file 

vidObj = cv2.VideoCapture(path) 

# Used as counter variable 
count = 0



while True: 

    # vidObj object calls read 
    # function extract frames 
    success, image = vidObj.read()

    if (success == False) 
     print("stop") break

    ## Convert the frame to gray color
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Main

```
if __name__ == '__main__': # Calling the function 
FrameCapture("/content/drive/My Drive/Development/EyeClose/BenKen.mp4")
```

The code should return all the extracted frames into grey image

Comment: What's the error message ? I would assume the infinite loop will keep converting empty image, once the video is done, so I would add some breaking point once success is False.

Comment: I also have the same feeling about it loop infinitely. May I know how to handle it using breaking point?

I got this error:
error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Comment: Use return value from VideoCapture.read,
if (success == False)
    print("stop")
    break

Comment: I would assume that's exactly where the error is coming from. I would try @unlut suggestion above to mitigate it (just to be clear put it just before "gray = ...").

Comment: Hi @unlut, thanks for the suggestion. However the following error was shot: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I follow your suggestion and implement as shown above

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski thanks for the detail suggestion, but I got an error. Need to do some googling about this

Comment: Right, try to rewrite it: ```if (success == False): break ``` and since it's python indents do matter.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski, thanks, it helps a lot. The previous error because I did not include the :